# ios: Create dynamic sqlite table using FMDB

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

```
NSString *mysql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE %@ (fname VARCHAR(100),lname VARCHAR(100),company VARCHAR(100),address1 VARCHAR(100),address2 VARCHAR(100),city VARCHAR(100),state VARCHAR(100),zip VARCHAR(100),email VARCHAR(100),phone VARCHAR(100));",businessType.tableName];
BOOL tableCreate = [db executeUpdate:mysql];
NSLog(@"table create = %d", tableCreate);
```

If i run this, with fresh run I will get `table create = 0`, but then If I change the code and make table name static and run the program, I will get `table create = 1` and again I change it back to dynamic table name(without reseting simulator) It will work fine, and now I can create as many table I want, but If I reset simulator and try, it wont work. dont know what is worng. please letme know, hope you understood my question.

Comment: please post the final sql you get in the two cases

Comment: please make sure db isn't nil the first time round

Comment: how to make sure of that my DB is not nil, I have no idea. I used to work in same way in some other project. I created db from sqlitemangager(firefox) and I am using it here.

Comment: this does not work at first, so I have to do 
NSString *mysql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE %@ (fname VARCHAR(100),lname VARCHAR(100),company VARCHAR(100),address1 VARCHAR(100),address2 VARCHAR(100),city VARCHAR(100),state VARCHAR(100),zip VARCHAR(100),email VARCHAR(100),phone VARCHAR(100));",@"test"];
and again back to code and change @"test" to variable name and it works.

Comment: please post the final sql strings.. NSLog(@"%@", mysql);